# Excel: Replace occurences of one character with another in a String?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string

I want an excel formula that will change `Haverford, PA` to `haverford,+pa`. (Text is to lowercase, and spaces are replaced with plus characters.)

The following will get the first space, but not all of them:

`=REPLACE(E19, SEARCH(" ", E19),1,"+")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Part of what you want to do can be accomplished with the "**SUBSTITUTE**" function.

This will replace specific characters in a text string with the characters you specify, in this case spaces with the  + symbol.

Then to change case use the "**LOWER**" function.

If you nest "SUBSTITUTE" within "LOWER" you should get the change you are looking for.

The text below is taken from Excel Help.

---

**SUBSTITUTE**

Substitutes new_text for old_text in a text string. Use SUBSTITUTE when you want to replace specific text in a text string; use REPLACE when you want to replace any text that occurs in a specific location in a text string.

Syntax

SUBSTITUTE(text,old_text,new_text,instance_num)

Text    is the text or the reference to a cell containing text for which you want to substitute characters.

Old_text    is the text you want to replace.

New_text    is the text you want to replace old_text with.

Instance_num    specifies which occurrence of old_text you want to replace with new_text. If you specify instance_num, only that instance of old_text is replaced. Otherwise, every occurrence of old_text in text is changed to new_text.

---

**LOWER**

Converts all uppercase letters in a text string to lowercase.

Syntax

LOWER(text)

Text    is the text you want to convert to lowercase. LOWER does not change characters in text that are not letters.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to replace all spaces with the '+' character, try:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(E19," ","+"))
```

Comment: An example is worth a thousand function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use find and replace to replace the entire Haverford, PA string with the one you want. You shouldn't need a formula for this, just the built in find and replace tool.

Comment: it's not just a one time thing. Users will put in human friendly strings, but I need them in a different form for URLs.